# Issue with Noscript XSS protection and Yahoo open-id login into superuser.com

Tags: discussion, support, openid, login

I couldn't log into superuser.com ( the first time I tried ) using Yahoo as my open-id provider because Noscript XSS protection kept flagging the attempt. I eventually had to disable XSS protection to be able to log in.

I didn't have this problem on any of the sister sites. 
Has anyone else seen this problem ?

Comment: If you will use an addon to restrict the functionality of sites, don't be surprised when sites stop working...

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue using my 1id.com OpenID, it was being detected as an XSS injection by NoScript even though both sites are allowed in NoScript. I found a solution by changing the noscript.injectionCheck configuration property mentioned on http://noscript.net/features#xss from the default 2 to 1.

This probably should not be used as a permanent solution but instead the details should be reported to the NoScript author so exceptions can be added to future versions.